# 'replacement transaction underpriced' when buying a token with web3

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I have a program where i buy a token, then sell it and then buy it again, if it was possible to sell. This is to check if it is a scam coin.
It is working but the second time i try to buy the token i run into this weird error:

ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}

I cannot fathom why it would come, as i just executed the buy function earlier with succes?

```
import json
from web3 import Web3
import time

bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
web3provider = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
sender_address = "youraddress"
privatekey = "key"
panRouterContractAddress ='0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'
uniswap_factory = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'  #Testnet  #0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17
panabi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'
uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')
contract = web3provider.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)
contractbuy = web3provider.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panabi)


def buy(token, amountToBuy):
    spend = web3provider.toChecksumAddress(
        "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c")  # wbnb contract address
    tokenToBuy = web3provider.toChecksumAddress(token)
    nonce = web3provider.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
    pancakeswap2_txn = contractbuy.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        web3provider.toWei(amountToBuy, 'ether'),
        0, 
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        sender_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        # 'value': 1000,
        # 'value': web3.toWei(amountToBuy, 'ether'),  
        'gasPrice': web3provider.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    signed_txn = web3provider.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn,
                                                   private_key=privatekey)
    tx_token = web3provider.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    transaction_tx = web3provider.toHex(tx_token)
    print("succesfull, bought: " + transaction_tx)

    return transaction_tx
```

```
[ERROR/2022-09-01 14:01:38,524] telethon.client.updates: Unhandled exception on handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 467, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\PycharmProjects\telegram_test\newtest.py", line 94, in handler
    sniped_tx = buy(tokenAddress, 0.0000001)
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\PycharmProjects\telegram_test\buy.py", line 37, in buy
    tx_token = web3provider.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 831, in send_raw_transaction
    return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\jeppe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs, when one is trying to substitute existing (presumably transaction with `pending` status).

It seems from the source code, that you didn't increment `nonce`. Try to use the following modification of code

```
...
nonce = web3provider.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
nonce += 1
...
```

Thus new transaction would be created instead of already sent ones.

Comment: Thank you for claryfying that part. I made a hack where i catch the error and try again each second, after around 5 seconds it buys the token. But i am happy to get to know the deeper concepts behind it all